# How do I add one extra non-rest url in my rest adaptor in ember js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a model called  `post`.

Apart from the restful apis, I have a non restful api `POST /posts/{post-id}/reschedule`.

How do I define and use the method for this custom api in my rest-adaptor?

I would want to call `myPostObj.reschedule(someParams)`.

Comment: I think you will just have to use Ember.$.post maybe use it in a method on your model.

Comment: Is there a way to re-use the existing serializers, coz i need to deserialize data as well.

Comment: are you returning data that will be loaded into the store?, will `JSON.parse()` not suffice?

Comment: The format of data is different. So need serializers to not duplicate logic.